# Scrolling box view like the new Google now

Tags: android, facebook, view, scroll, google-now

I'm kind of new to Android development and wanted to create a fragment like the new Google Now screen with the boxes, or the Android Facebook App wall screen in which every post is in a custom "box".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're just using a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

A ListView is not something trivial to tackle for a beginner. Since the guide I pointed you to may not be enough, [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) is a 1 hour video on ListViews made by Romain Guy and Chet Haase on YouTube (Romain Guy is the guy who wrote ListView for Android and Chet Haase who wrote the animation framework for Android).

For an example that mimics that boxed look that you can play around with, download [DevApps Direct](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect) on your device. All the samples DevApps showcases are open source.

Scroll to "ListView Animations" > "Google Cards Example" > "Run Demo"

Code [available here](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations).

You might also want to take a look at some of the other samples DevApps Direct has: "Card Library", "SugaredListAnimations Sample", "Pull to Refresh", "SwipeListView Demo", etc.

Comment: Thanks! that heled a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing, I had to do quite same thing months ago...

Just a ListView incremented with whatever you want(text, images, etc) ... it is necessary a adapter as well, otherwise you will not have a nice view !